# Javascript- Setting Input Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

EDIT: As this question turned out to be quite a bit different than originally stated, please refer instead to [HTML- Altering Input Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17796675/html-alerting-input-value)

I have an input element that I am trying to set while I'm creating a pair of tables (the value should reflect the total value of the row).  However, the statement is not working for some reason.  The basics of the code are as follows:

```
prevTotalElt = $('#TimeSheetTable #ProjectData #projectBody #' + curProj + '_total');
alert(prevTotalElt.val() + '\n' + prevTotalVal);
prevTotalElt.val(prevTotalVal);
```

This code is in an if statement, and the alert message appears as expected with the proper values.  The weirdest bit is that the same statement executes at the end of the loop (to take care of the final total element in the table) and works perfectly.  I can't really understand what the issue is here, but any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Due to requests, here is the line that creates the `input` element I am trying to set:

```
$('#TimeSheetTable #ProjectData #projectBody').html($('#TimeSheetTable #ProjectData #projectBody').html() +
    '<tr><td align="center"><input id="' + curProj + '_total" type="number"' +
    'align="center" value="' + tmpInd + '" style="width:17px; border:none;" disabled></td>');
```

Comment: We would need to see your HTML. What if your JS does not properly reflect what is in your HTML? That could easily be the issue here.

Comment: Which type of element is `prevTotalElt` like `input`, `div`

Comment: It is an input.  And the JS reflects the proper paths- it shows the value that is in the `input` element, and the value sets properly just after the loop (using the `prevTotalElt.val(prevTotalVal);` statement).

Comment: Your code looks fine then, make sure you don't have multiple `elements` with same `id`

Comment: I don't- I checked, and they all have the proper ID.  I can't understand why it is working in one place and not another (there is only one line in my code that sets prevTotalElt, and I copied and pasted the line that sets its value just to make sure that there are no spelling errors).

Comment: May be there are more than one event handler and something else is also changing the value of input, if not then please add the `HTML` markup in the question.

Comment: IDs inside of IDs in selectors are a sign that you're doing something wrong

Comment: This actually isn't an event handler- it is just the creation of the page.  No events have been fired at this point.  @Juan Mendes what do you mean by IDs inside of IDs?

Comment: He mean's you don't need `$('#TimeSheetTable #ProjectData #projectBody #' + curProj + '_total');` instead you should use `$('#' + curProj + '_total');`

Comment: I suppose that is probably a better idea, but I am inserting my code into a MS Sharepoint site, and it makes me a bit nervous since I'm not really sure what all they are doing as far as other element names on the page, so I'm trying to play it on the safe side.  Is there a performance penalty to having multiple identifiers?  Or is this due to readability concerns?  I'd be interested to hear a bit more about it.

Comment: Yes performance penalty is there, for single `id` native `javascript` `getElementById` will be used. As for your issue search `$('#TimeSheetTable #ProjectData #projectBody').html` and make sure it's not at multiple places and it's before `prevTotalElt.val(prevTotalVal);`, Also alert the value after setting to input as you have alerted before setting the value

Comment: @Crash I mean that `$('#TimeSheetTable #ProjectData #projectBody').html()` should be  `$('#projectBody').html()` because you're only allowed only item with a given ID

Comment: @Manoj I think you might have found something there- I hadn't tried it, but after I set that value, the alert claims that the element has the right value.  However, it doesn't stay that way.  Is it possible that setting the value in this way doesn't affect the value of the HTML element?  If that is the case, the fact that I am including the existing HTML when I add each row of the table may be resetting the value of the `input` element.

Comment: Actually, I just checked and the change does not affect the HTML.  How can I go about doing this?  Is it possible that I could append to the existing HTML without resetting it?

Comment: I think what is happening here is that you are changing the input value in `#projectBody` html and after that `#projectBody` html getting replace by something else so your change is not reflecting. comment the `$('#TimeSheetTable #ProjectData #projectBody').html(` code block then you may get some clue

Comment: It seems to be that the #projectBody HTML is being replaced by the #projectBody HTML (i.e. `$('#projectBody').html($('#projectBody').html() + <next_table_line>);`).  Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: I don't thing the issue is because of this but you can try `append` method `$('#projectBody').append(<next_table_line>);`

Comment: Actually, that's exactly what it turned out to be- Just ended up finding the method on another spot.  Go ahead and post it as the answer if you want the rep points.

Comment: Glad that you have found the solution of this issue.