# HTML- Altering Input Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I recently posted a similar question, but after some discussion, the question turned out to be quite a bit different than it was originally stated, so I thought it best to post this as a new question.  I am trying to use an input field to show a total (I would consider using another element type, but I need to do the same thing in other places where an input field is actually required, so I may as well fix the problem now).  The problem is that the HTML of the table containing these fields needs to be reloaded on occasion, i.e. in table creation, I use the Jquery `$('#table1').html($('#table1').html() + <next_table_line>);`.  This causes the input field to revert to the value displayed in its `value` attribute, which doesn't change when I use the `$('#input1').val(<some_value>);` setter or when I enter data manually.  Does anyone know of a solution to my problem?  I need to be able to add rows to the table without loosing my data, but I can't figure out how to do this.

Comment: You are going to have to paste some code. This is way too general a problem statement for us to possible divine a solution.

Comment: Why are you reloading the table like that...just append?

Comment: That's approximately the answer I am looking for- will append not reload the existing HTML?

Comment: Nope, just target your table, and use `.append` and load up a new row.

Comment: @tymeJV that worked perfectly- I didn't know that method.  Please post this as an answer.

Comment: @Crash -- Already done :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're reloading your entire table with the line `$('#table1').html($('#table1').html() + <next_table_line>);`. You should be appending to your table instead. Take the following sample small table:

```
<table id="test">
    <tr><td>test</td></tr>
</table>
```

Now, to add a new row, dont re-write the entire table HTML, just append!

```
$("#test").append("<tr><td>See im new!</td></tr>");
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uB2Rq/1/

Comment: Thanks!  I'll mark this as the answer in a few minutes when I am allowed to.